# Why does everything written on a page appear in concentric circles when we rotate that page?

Tags: visible-light, kinematics, vision, perception

When i put a pencil in the middle of a paper and rotate it very fast, whatsoever is written on it, will appear in concentric circles. What is the reason behind this phenomenon and what is it called?

Comment: Persistence of vision, is that you mean, perhaps?

Comment: This has to do with physiology (specifically, the way your brain processes images) and not really physics.

Comment: But something MUST be related to physics here! @Sean

Comment: There *might* be some in the kinematics, but your *perception* is not physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the physiology of vision and not physics.

Answer (score 2):

Fast things appear blurry to your eyes, and the distance from a point on the paper to your pencil is fixed. The distance from an ink dot on the paper, to the tip of your pencil where you press down, cannot change. Call this distance $d$. The only positions the point is allowed to be at when you spin the page around, are positions that satisfy the equation $x^2+y^2=d^2$, with $d$ being constant. The set of solutions of that equation is a circle, so things appear as circles.

To add a lesson that has nothing to do with your question, $x^2+y^2$ has an intimate connection with euclidean geometry. $x^2-t^2$ ("$t$" for "time") has an intimate connection with special relativity! The analogous things to circles in euclidean geometry are hyperbolas in special relativity.

Comment: What do you mean by, by your pushing down, according to x2+y2=d2, with d being constant.

Comment: @AaryanDewan I added some clarification. Let me know if that helps. Also: you can type in x^2+y^2=d^2 with dollar signs around the equation to write "$x^2+y^2=d^2$". This is using LaTeX.